# ASP.NET Core Web App Page Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created a brand new ASP.NET Core Web App project to test out the new features of .NET 6.0.

[image: Create ASP.NET Core Web App Screen]

But when I tried to run the application with F5 nothing displayed on the web browser but "Page Not Found" error.

Also I tried with IIS Express and the result is same. Also tried http and it's same.

I don't have any idea what may be the problem?

[image: Page not found screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I rebooted my computer project runs well.

But sometimes later problem occurred again. I tried changing ports, rebooting, close and relaunch visual studio. None of them solved the problem.

Must be a computer specific problem but don't have any idea where to start. Really annoying.

So I keep searching and trying, I came up with this solution:
[ASP.NET Core 404 Error on IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529123/asp-net-core-404-error-on-iis-10)

```
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

It works for now but the problem related to debugging still persists.